# Is a life sentence necessary for all potential murderers in The Minority Report

Tags: minority-report

For the sake of keeping things tidy, I will make this point clear.  This question pertains to the short story, not the movie and not the TV series.

The prophylactic incarceration of criminals in The Minority Report is a truly fascinating concept.  Obviously the morality or immorality of punishing people for crimes they have not yet committed is at the heart of the story's theme, but my question is more focused on the practicality of the situation.

The short story made no distinction between crimes of passion and premeditated crime, and this creates an interesting problem.  The problem being that crimes of passion are different in a very important way when applied to a concept like Pre-Crime.  A crime of passion is lightning in a bottle.  It is the product of multiple specific elements combining at just the right time.  A crime of passion is not the product of criminal intent.  A premeditated crime by comparison is the product of criminal intent and therefore less dependent on perfect environmental factors.

So when we apply these different types of crimes to Pre-Crime, we see two very different implications.  By stopping a man from murdering a business rival, you have prevented a murder, but that murder is only prevented for as long as the would-be criminal is denied the ability to carry out his plans.  By stopping the mild mannered salary man from murdering his wife when he came home early to find her in bed with his neighbor, you have prevented that murder indefinitely.  The murder that would have been committed in the heat of passion can only happen in that moment of passion.  **So why is it necessary to imprison him for life?**

Bear in mind, it is expensive to incarcerate an individual for life.  You are reducing the labor pool and you are adding to the tax payers' financial burden.  Surely it would be in the best interests of Pre-Crime to permanently incarcerate only those would-be criminals that pose a clear and present threat, and temporarily incarcerate the individuals that pose a temporary threat?

One potential answer I had considered was "There is no guarantee that the man who caught his wife cheating on him won't try to kill her at some later date."  But this answer forgets that Pre-Crime exists.  If the cuckolded man decides to murder his wife a month after discovering the affair, then Pre-Crime will arrest him for attempted premeditated murder.  There is no reason to assume that the individual who tried to kill his wife in the heat of passion, would go on to be a murderer at a later date.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head in what made me not enjoy an otherwise fun movie.  In logic we call that a False Dilemma, or more specifically a False Binary

Comment: My memory is a little fuzzy when it comes to logic (I just made at least one philosopher smirk), so I am afraid I must shamefully confess that I cannot spot the specific false binary you are referring to.  Would you mind helping me feel less dumb by enlightening me on what you are referring to?

Comment: Essentially you're being arrested and jailed for the murder you would have committed. The fact that you didn't actually get the chance to commit it is neither here nor there.

Comment: You can argue that this world has adopted a viewpoint that there are good people who would never murder and evil people who are capable of murder under the right circumstances.  Those evil people should be removed from society (but of course we can't kill them or we would be evil).

Comment: True @Valorum, but incarceration is not just about punishment.  It is also about protecting society from dangerous individuals.  What Pre-Crime does is essentially shift the focus away from punishment and onto prophylaxis.  The holding of would-be murderers is a prophylactic measure, not a punitive measure.  With that in mind, why prophylacticly hold individuals when they no longer pose a threat?

Comment: @Magikarp Master The idea of a False Binary is to create 2 choices.  1 imprison people for precrime forever, maybe some innocent, or 2 disband the project.  The fallacy is not acknowledging that the decision is not binary and shades of gray exist like only stopping the crime, but not arresting anyone for more than 24 hrs for a phych evaluation

Comment: @Andrey Many thanks.  I'm still a tad embarrassed for missing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [original short story](http://cwanderson.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Philip-K-Dick-The-Minority-Report.pdf) (on which the film is quite closely based) is informative. Would-be criminals are identified and kept away from civilised people. **They have the genetic propensity to commit murder and hence are no longer welcome in society.**

Note that the fact that they didn't actually *manage* to commit their vile crimes is neither relevant, nor of particular interest to the authorities.

> *They had come to the descent lift. As it carried them swiftly downward, Anderton said: “You’ve probably
>   already grasped the basic legalistic drawback to precrime methodology. We’re taking in individuals who have
>   broken no law.”
>
>    “But surely, they will,” Witwer affirmed with conviction.
>
>    “Happily, they don’t — because we get to them first, before they can commit an act of violence. So the
>   commission of the crime itself is absolute metaphysics. We can claim they are culpable. They, on the other
>   hand, can eternally claim they’re innocent. And, in a sense, they are innocent.”
>
>    The lift let them out, and they again paced down a yellow corridor. **“In our society, we have no major
>   crimes,” Anderton went on, “but we do have a detention camp full of would-be criminals.”***
>
> <sub><sup>[Philip K. Dick - The Minority Report](http://cwanderson.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Philip-K-Dick-The-Minority-Report.pdf)</sup></sub>

Of course, in the original story prisoners are shipped off to the offworld colonies to work as prison labourers, so the cost of keeping them is defrayed by the results of their labour. In the film they're just frozen and ignored.